# Having to add additional dependencies to react useCallback dependency list

Tags: javascript, reactjs, usecallback

I'm trying to create a custom hook function that uses `useCallback`
 function. Here's a toy example:

```
export function useCustomLink(link: { url: string; description: string }) {

  const [updating, setUpdating] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [linkInfo, setLinkInfo] = useState<{ url: string; description: string } | "loading" | "error">("loading");

  useEffect(() => {
    // initiate linkInfo
    if (!updating) {
      setLinkInfo(link);
    }
  }, [link]);

  const updateLink = useCallback((update: Partial<{ url: string; description: string }>) => {
    if (linkInfo !== 'loading' && linkInfo !== 'error') {
      const updated = { ...linkInfo, ...update };
      setLinkInfo(updated);
      setUpdating(true);
    }
  }, [linkInfo, link]);


  return {
    linkInfo, updateLink
  };
}
```

My understanding of the dependency list is that I only need to add variables that are directly used by the function (in this case, `linkInfo`). However, if I don't add `link` (which is passed into the custom hook function) into the list as well, then I would end up with stale states of `linkInfo`. Can anyone help explain why I need to add the add'l variable into the dependencies? Is this the correct way to use `useCallback`?

Thanks!

Comment: Before that, do you know why you need `useCallback` in this case?

Comment: @DennisVash I thought it would speed up the performance? Do you think it's unnecessary to use `useCallback` here?

Comment: Please read the docs beforehand, it doesnt help you here.